How would I find a ROM for this Chinese tablet?
I have a generic Chinese tablet (Model: Gener8 7", 2GB RAM, 16GB storage, running Android 10?). I want to install a lightweight custom ROM to improve its performance, but I can't find any ROMs for this specific device.
I've searched XDA-Developers and other forums but haven't found anything for this tablet. Does anyone have any idea of some compatible custom ROMs?
Here is the link for the tablet.

Sorry, we can't help finding available ROM, we can only provide how/where to find them (if any) because the availability of custom ROM depends on some factors, like unlockable bootloader, kernel blob and device tree provided by the manufacturer, and existing users who tinker with this device model specifically.

Can you give me instruction on how to find this?
